# How to encrypt(Salt) an url parameter in WSO2IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am seeing WSO2 url like
https://example.com/commonauth?sessionDataKey=cbea1fe2-b2g5-4703-9c04-9d142f70bc6f&type=samlsso

But for some security reasons I want to encrypt(salt) the url parameters. Is there any way to do in WSO2IS. I am using WSO2 identity Server 5.1.0.

Comment: I believe there was a security patch for 5.1.0 which would delete the sessionDataKey after being used, but I am unable to find back links for the patches of the 5.1.0 anymore..

Comment: Thanks @gusto2 . I am migrating to 5.3.0. Is this available in 5.3.0?

Comment: I believe it should be so. The sessionDataKey should be deleted / invalidated. Test it first, I don't have access to my installation at this moment